# change background-color of radio buttons if not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, radio-button

As soon as the user submits without having checked all radio buttons, the unanswered buttons should appear in a different background-color than the ones checked. The way I tried to implement this was:

1. create an empty array - "store"
2. loop over each radio button and push the number 1 (true) in the array "store" if the item has  been checked and 0(false) otherwise.
3. Then I wanna loop over this array and add a Class to those items which have the value zero in "store".

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#form').submit(function(){
           var isValid = true; 
           var store = new Array();
           $("input:radio").each(function() {
               if($(this).prop('checked',true)){
                   store.push(1);}
               else{
                   store.push(0);
                   isValid = false;}           
           }); //.each
               if(!isValid){
                   for(var i=0;i < store.length;i++){
                       if(store[i]===0){
                           $('input[name=item' + i +']').addClass("not_answered");}
                       }//end of for-loop
                   return false;}
               else{
                   return true;}

       }); //submit
   });//document ready
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

My fiddle:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P7UgE/)

Comment: Here's a fun test, add the class to the elements and see if the radio button can be styled like that -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/P7UgE/1/

Comment: once you have run the test, and see that you cannot apply background color to a radio input like that, either wrap each one in the div, or create labels for radio  input and apply class to them.

Comment: Mistake #1 is in your fiddle. The form has the wring ID `id="#form"`. Should be `id="form"`

Comment: I totally forgot to check if radios have this style. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: I figured it out, it should just say `prop('checked')`.

Comment: @beginneR I think you can simplify this, see my answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify this a little [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pobayanu/1/edit):

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
   var radios = $(this).find('input:radio').removeClass('notChecked');
   radios.filter(':not(:checked)').addClass('notChecked');
   if(radios.hasClass('notChecked')) return false;
});
```